# How to read/extract content of multipart/form-data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multipartform-data

I am receiving a multipart/form-data that contains an image and a string but i could not extract the content.

A. The code below is reading the `string` content but it only reads when the string is appended first before the image and reading the image with code below(B) returns nothing

```
string expenseid = context.Request["ExpenseID"];
```

B. The code below is reading the image but it only reads when the image is appended first and reading the string with the code above(A) returns nothing.

```
HttpPostedFile uploadedfile = context.Request.Files[0];
string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(uploadedfile.FileName);
```

I would like to know the proper reading of content of multipart/form-data that contains a `string` and an image.

Comment: Are you receiving this from a regular form-post?  If so, I'm not sure what the problem is.  The Request.Form collection will contain all fields in the POST-ed data, and Request.Files will contain all files.

Comment: Include the form in the question

Answer (score 0):

The script you would need to send for a file and some other fields with it.

```
//Purpose: Form Submit: SAVE (Here the file plus form data is saved
        document.getElementById('frmPage').onsubmit = function (e) {
            debugger;
            var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
            var filename;
            if (file) {
                filename = file.name;
            }
            else {
                filename = "";
            }
            $('#Image').val(filename);
            var formObj = $(this);
            var formURL = '@Url.Action("SaveMethod", "ControllerName")';
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: formURL,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    debugger;

                    alert("Client saved successfully");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //Prevent Default action.
        }
```

This is the design:

```
<div>

                            <form id="frmPage" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-body">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label id="lblImage" class="col-md-3 control-label">Upload File</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" />

                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                                <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top: 0px">
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn blue Save">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

Here: The btnSave is submit type, so it will submit that particular form. and form named frmPage will do the jquery script we added. That will save the file and also page data.

Comment: Wow! Thanks this was very informative. The data that contains a string and an image is sent from IOS. I am receiving it through a webservice and I had difficulty reading the string and image simultaneously.

Comment: Alright, so is the iOS app native? if so I do have some code I think that I have used.

Comment: I'm Using Xcode 5. I am able to sendpost in IOS with the string and image and sends the multipart/form-data to the web service in C#. However reading the contents of the data in C# is my roadblock :) Thank you..